# is it ok to regroup resolved data from angularjs config function into one object

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs config function, I have about 5 calls to fetch data from my backend. like:

```
resolve : {
     data_one : [function(){ ... }],
     data_two : [function(){ ... }],
     data_five : [function(){ ... }]
}
```

So I have a lot of resolve properties injected in my controller. I know I can use a service, but is it ok if I just compose tem into one object like this :

```
resolve : {
     data_1 : [function(){ ... }],
     data_2 : [function(){ ... }],
     data_3 : [function(){ ... }],
     // composing
     allData : [ "data_1", "data_2", "data_5", function(d1, d2, d5) {
           return {
              "d1" : d1,
              "d2" : d2,
              "d3" : d3 
           };
     }]
}
```

is it good or bad practice ? less efficient ? "memoryvore" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any harm with this approach. Basically this will obviously going to reduce the headache of adding multiple dependency inside controller factory function. So this could improve the code readability on the controller side as well.

### Q & A

> **It can be good/bad practice?**
>
> If there are more than 3-4 resolve function the I'd really go for
>   regrouping them (good practice), otherwise don't go for it (bad
>   practice).
>
> **less efficient?**
>
> No, it won't.

Comment: Fantastic ! what about memory, any chance to have duplicated object? (or it's ok because the composed resolve object is pointing to a reference)